# Why can't I change the isolation levels of my connection in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, transaction, isolation-level

I am trying to experiment a bit with the isolation level of MySQL in a test environment.
I do the following:

```
mysql> set @@session.tx_isolation='READ-UNCOMMITED';
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'tx_isolation' can't be set to the value of 'READ-UNCOMMITED'
```

This also fails:

```
mysql> update information_schema.session_variables set variable_value='READ-UNCOMMITED' where variable_name='TX_ISOLATION';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am root. So it should not be a rights issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to try

```
SET tx_isolation = 'READ-UNCOMMITTED';
```

or

```
SET SESSION tx_isolation = 'READ-UNCOMMITTED';
```

You could also [declare it at the start of the transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

Please note that you misspelled `READ-UNCOMMITED` (Missing `T`). It should be `READ-UNCOMMITTED`

You cannot change `tx_isolation` in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database because it is an in-memory read-only database.

Comment: +1 for finding the spelling mistake. Nevertheless `set @@session.tx_isolation='READ-UNCOMMITTED'` is a valid statement.

Comment: @ShlomiNoach you are right. That `set` is the type of syntax used in the header of mysqldumps.